# Vertex ai custom model training for pyspark ml model

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, machine-learning-model, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is it possible to train a spark/pyspark ML lib model using VertexAI custom container model building? I couldn't find any reference in the vertex ai documents regarding spark model training. For distributed processing model building only options available are PyTorch or TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with custom containers if you leverage the Spark Kubernetes operator but this is not a well documented workflow and will require complex set up.  GCP's preferred way to run Spark jobs is on Dataproc https://cloud.google.com/dataproc which supports PySpark, SparkR, Scala.  You can still trigger a Dataproc Spark job from Vertex Pipelines and save the model for predictions in Vertex via MLeap.